# Why does Mathematica gives a solution which is not in the domain of the cot function?

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry, singularity

I've tried to solve the equation $\cot \theta = 2 \cot 2\theta$
with the command `Reduce` and *Mathematica* gave $\theta = n\pi$ as solution, with $n$ an integer. But $\theta = n\pi$ is not in the domain of the cotangent function so this result is quite confusing.

I understand that both curves "meet" at infinity at the angles suggested by *Mathematica* but it is mathematically incorrect to assume a solution which is not included in the domain of the function.

On the other side:

```
Reduce[Cot[t] == 2 Cot[2 t], t, Reals]
```

gives `False` as result, which is the mathematically consistent answer AFAIK.

Therefore, it is pretty clear for me that the problem arises when you do not specify the domain but, as infinity is not any number, I cannot conceive any domain in which $t=n\pi$ is a solution of the above equation. Then, why is *Mathematica* giving this solution? Is it an inconsistency or am I missing something?

Comment: `Plot[{Cot[t], Cot[t] - 2 Cot[2 t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]`

Comment: Alternatively, you can consider the fact that `Cot[t] - 2 Cot[2 t] == Tan[t]`. Try `Simplify[Cot[t] - 2 Cot[2 t]]`.

Comment: Also `Simplify[Cot[t]/(2 Cot[2 t]) /. t -> n Pi, Element[n, Integers]]` evaluates to `1`

Comment: I wonder why should specifying `Reals` give a different result?

Comment: Consider the function `f[t_] := Cot[t]-2Cot[2 t]`. As you observed, the result `Reduce[f[t]==0, t]` is incorrect; all proposed solutions are outside the domain of `f` (they are solutions of the continuous extension of `f`). Here is something similar: `Solve[f[t] == 0 && Abs[t] < 10, t, VerifySolutions -> True]` gives 7 solution, but neither is correct.` f[t] /. %` returns 7 Indeterminate's. I am wondering why VerifySolutions does not work here.

Comment: The thing is that when you operate you have to take into account the domain and $\cot[t] - 2\cot[2t]$ cannot be $\tan[t]$ for the simple reason that the function $\cot$ and $\tan[t]$ have different domains. My point here is that whenever you operate with Reduce, Simplify, Plot, or whichever the command from Mathematica if you don't specify the domain the result appears to be mathematically inconsistent. Also i have obtained another result that could shed some light into this question. When i try: $Reduce[Cot[t] == 2*Cot[2*t], t, Complexes]$ with Complexes instead Reals I obtain $n\pi$ too.